# Other than astronauts, did any equipment go to the moon more than once?

Tags: the-moon, apollo-program, astronauts

It's been well documented elsewhere that three astronauts made multiple trips to the moon (whether to just orbit it, or actually land), these being Lovell, Young, and Cernan.  Other than these 3 astronauts, was any significant equipment or hardware flown more than once on any of the Apollo missions that went to the moon?  This could also include any general good-luck charms, or other items of general interest rather than possible personal mementos by the 3 astronauts listed above.

Comment: My intent was to indicate anything that made it as far as the moon, whether landing or not.  I'll reword the title a bit.